# Reverse cumulative sum until condition is met in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I have the following dataframe:

```
frame=pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b"], data=[(2,5),(2,6),(1,8),(1,1),(3,5),(3,2),(3,3)])
```

which looks like this:

```
    a   b
0   2   5
1   2   6
2   1   8
3   1   1
4   3   5
5   3   2
6   3   3
```

I want to do a reverse cumulative sum of column "b" until condition is met - column "a" is the same number - in this particular example - 3. Desired output is `10`.

Comment: Could you give the output for the whole column, is not entirely clear what is should be

Comment: The desired output is not columnwise. I just want to sum the numbers in column "b" from back to front and keep doing so until the number in column "a" is the same. Meaning the desired output is number 10 as per the example.

Comment: You mean *while* the number in column a is the same and not *until*, right ?

Comment: @IsmaelELATIFI -  Exactly

Comment: The condition is that a == b or that a has the same value?

Comment: 'a' has the same values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your logic:

```
 blocks = frame['a'].ne(frame['a'].shift()).cumsum()

 frame.loc[blocks==blocks.iloc[-1], 'b'].sum()
 # 10
```